# Cocoa - NSNetserviceErrorCode = -72003

Tags: cocoa, networking

Hiyee...Now I'm having this error " NSNetServicesErrorCode = -72003; NSNetServicesErrorDomain = 10; " when I was trying to connect  to a domain.

My Code for connection:

```
-(IBAction)connect:(id)sender {
    NSNetService *remoteService = servicesController.selectedObjects.lastObject;
    remoteService.delegate = self;
    [remoteService resolveWithTimeout:30];
}
```

Error Code:

```
-(void)netService:(NSNetService *)service didNotResolve:(NSDictionary *)errorDict {
    NSLog(@"Could not resolve: %@", errorDict);
}
```

---

Thankz

Answer (score 2):

This is [documented in the documentation for the underlying CFNetwork library](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Networking/Reference/CFNetworkErrors/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCFNetServiceErrorInProgress). (If you look a little bit up the page, you'll see that that name has the value you found in your error dictionary.)

Comment: hmm...I have check the description of the error code...[The net service is busy and cannot process the request]... But now I'm having difficulties in solving...Thankz for the reply anyway

Comment: No, that's not what the error code means. See the documentation I linked to.

Comment: Valid answer until the link breaks. "A new search could not be started because a search is already in progress."

Answer (score 0):

`kCFNetServiceErrorInProgress = -72003L`

from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cfnetwork/cfnetworkerrors/kcfnetserviceerrorinprogress